# Cocos2D/Box2d Setting velocity in only one axis

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, box2d, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to simulate some real jump physics with setVelocity using Box2d in Cocos2d x C++.
My commands are like:

```
switch (keyCode){
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_LEFT_ARROW:
    physicsBody->setVelocity(Vec2(75, 0));
    mySprite1->setPhysicsBody(physicsBody3);
break;
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_RIGHT_ARROW:
    physicsBody3->setVelocity(Vec2(-75,0));
    mySprite1->setPhysicsBody(physicsBody3);
break;
case EventKeyboard::KeyCode::KEY_UP_ARROW:
    physicsBody3->setVelocity(Vec2(0,200));
    mySprite1->setPhysicsBody(physicsBody3);
break;
```

}

However, as it is clear to me, whenever i change the velocity in one axis, the other axis gets one.
The problem is: i'm unable to run and jump (the jump stops the running).

I need some way to change the velocity in only one axis at a time, so that my jump don't interfere with my run. That or another way to do tat exact same thing. I'm open to ideas regarding the physics since i'm a newbie in game programming.

Comment: Obviously you should not modify the .X of the velocity when jumping: get the current velocity, set the new .Y, and set it as the new velocity.

Comment: So i'm using now Vec2 v = physicsBody3->getVelocity();
and i'm altering only v.y = 200; in the arrow up case
and using physicsBody3->setVelocity(v); in the arrow up case
and it's no use, my running is still being interrupted by the jump

Comment: Why not apply force/impluse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ApplyLinearImpulse to get the effect that you are looking for.

```
// Apply linear impulse only in x-direction
physicsBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec(75, 0),  physicsBody->GetPosition(), true);
// Apply the jump impulse
physicsBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(b2Vec(0, 200),  physicsBody->GetPosition(), true);
```

The above code will apply impulse and add to the current velocity. Which means that when you jump you will keep moving in the x-direction. This is code from one of my projects so I can confirm that it works.